# PouchDB replication speed up?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using CouchDB/PouchDB as an off-line tile server for a Cordova mapping app.  Initial replication of the CouchDB 215mb db on phone takes over two hours on local network.  CouchDB to CouchDB replication takes 6 minutes on local network.  Db includes 65000 documents with png attachments of 1-2KB.

```
function managePouchDB(networkState) {
        // replicate tiles from local workstation
        var remoteCouchdb_osm_bc = "http://192.168.12.5:5984/osm_bc_simple_z6-13_tiles";
        var tiledb_rep_opts = {
            // http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication
            live: true,
            retry: true,
            // batch size: tried 10 - 100; 10 works best for osm tiles replication w/ nginx
            batch_size: 10, // default = 100
            attachments: true
        };

        // replicate osm bc tiles on check
        var pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer_replicate = pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.replicate.from(remoteCouchdb_osm_bc, tiledb_rep_opts);
        var pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_storedState = localStorage.getItem("pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_storedState");
        if (pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_storedState === "true") {
            pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.replicate.from(remoteCouchdb_osm_bc, tiledb_rep_opts);
```

I have reduced batch size, which yields a reduction in replication time, but still only see ~ 2mb/min replication.

Online CouchDB tiles called directly display well.  Using CouchDB V1.6.1, PouchDB V4.0.3

Where would the probable bottlenecks be?  Solutions or ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As Alex said, you can use `pouchdb-load` for faster replications.

However, the slowness will be fixed automatically in CouchDB 1.7 and CouchDB 2.0 when those get released, so you can just wait for that. I believe Cloudant has already shipped the fix as well. See [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2310) for details on the speedup.

Answer (score 1):

The replication protocoll es extremely chatty. That cost's a lot of time in initial replication.

Check out this tool: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load

Comment: Thanks.  Looks to be what I needed.

Worked the simplest case into code to test.  Getting errors:
GET http://192.168.x.x:2092/data/osm_bc_simple_z6-13_tiles_dump_dec1420151306.txt
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

And this one:
PouchDB: the remote database may not have CORS enabled.If not please enable CORS: http://pouchdb.com/errors.html#no_access_control_allow_origin_header

CORS has allows been enabled.

Comment: I think I had the same problem the first time: Try adding "x-csrf-token" to "cors" > "headers"

Answer (score 0):

My added code:

```
var remoteCouchdb_osm_bc_dump ="http://192.x.x.x:8092/data/osm_tiles_dump.txt";

if ((pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_storedState === "true") && (networkState === "WiFi_connection" || "wifi")) {
   pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.load(remoteCouchdb_osm_bc_dump , {
        proxy: remoteCouchDB_osm_bc
   }).then(function () {
        // done loading! handoff to regular replication
        console.log("Done loading osm dump to PouchDB");
        pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.info().then(console.log.bind(console));
        return pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.replicate.from(remoteCouchdb_osm_bc, tiledb_rep_opts);        
   }).catch(function (err) {
         // HTTP error or something like that
         console.log("error on osm_bc dump to PouchDB");
});
```

Doesn't throw the above errors when run from phone, but causes app to crash & restart. Doesn't happen without the db.load.  Dump file downloads in less than 1 minute to phone, all docs seem to be in db per

```
pouchTilesDB_osm_bc_baselayer.info().then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Then throws error and crashes.

CORS errors were thrown when debugging in Chromium and got sorted via Access-Control-Allow-Origin: for Nginx (http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html). Had short=circuit, CORS error was from accessing dump.txt file, not CouchDB.  Doesn't show for Cordova app in phone.

While a replication is "chatty" that does not fully explain why CouchDB to PouchDB is so much slower than CouchDB to CouchDB replication.  Will test CouchDB 2.0.

I can wget dump file from laptop.  Took 41s.